# iOS : Is it possible to allocate free disc space just for reading in an iOS app

Tags: ios

I am interested to know if it is possible to allocate free disc space just for reading in an iOS app. The background of this question is a security issue.

Say you have an app A running in sandbox that stores user documents in its app private folder. This data uses some disc space that is only reachable from app A. Because of the sandbox an app B cannot access this user documents. If app A deletes the user documents there will be only deleted the inodes that references the documents. The disc space that is used by the documents are already there but nobody links to it and is so marked as free disc space. If app B now allocates the whole free disc space and reads bytewise the whole allocated space, where also the user documents are, app B can access the user documents. Theoretically.

To protect the user documents there are some ideas. The first is the encryption of the documents. By deletion they are still encrypted. But they are also still accessible. The next idea is to override the documents before deletion. But the disc space is a Flash storage what means that at the moment the data will be changed they are moved nondeterministically to other locations in the Flash. That means this does also not help.

I figured out that it is possible to allocate free heap space by using
`UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate` and read then bytewise the allocated space with `UnsafeMutableRawPointer.load`. I don't know if this is also possible for disc space. In [this](https://medium.com/@robdeans/exploring-ioss-sandbox-b72e4697ab2f) article I read that there are three options to access the disc space `FileHandle`, `FileManager`, and `Data`. But all of them, so I think, can only read files not bytes of disc space.

In the documentation archive from Apple, I can not find an answer, if this scenario is really possible or not. I hope someone else have a tip where I can find the information that I am looking for or maybe have an answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each file on the file system is encrypted with a unique key; even if a malicious app was to request a disk allocation and attempt to read the free space, it would not obtain any information since it would not posses the necessary decryption keys.

You can read more about this in [The iOS security publication](https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) from Apple:

> ## File Data Protection
>
> In addition to the hardware encryption features built into iOS devices, Apple uses a technology called Data Protection to further protect data stored in flash memory on the device. Data Protection allows the device to respond to common events such as incoming phone calls, but also enables a high level of encryption for user data. Key system apps, such as Messages, Mail, Calendar, Contacts, Photos, and Health data values use Data Protection by default, and third-party apps installed on iOS 7 or later receive this protection automatically.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I am looking for.